# sandbox not hitting notifyurl

Tags: paypal

This seems to be a common problem but I can't seem to find any solutions for it. I have used the Ipn simulator testing and it works fine, but when I test out a transation by going through the payment process Paypal never hits my Ipn Listener. I am currently testing in the sandbox

I am using the Express Checkout API and setting the NotifyUrl in the **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** method. Why is paypal not hitting the url specified in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the documentation and version I were using didn't match up, so I was using deprecated parameters. For some reason using deprecated commands does not throw any errors, so it is hard to debug.

Paypal does a real good job of hiding their documentation and making it difficult to match API version with documentation version.

Answer (score 0):

To take a stab, are you sure the URL is accessible by paypal?  Paypal is calling it so urls like localhost will not work.  If it is https and you're using a development certificate that might explain it as well.  Is your firewall possibly blocking it?

Comment: The site is public and we have accessed the url and there we no problems. We are also using the signature instead of the certificate, so there is no firewall issue that I can think of. We have another site hosted on the same server and it works. We have compared the requests and don't see anything different between them...